nextjs web app with nginx as reverse proxy, slows down after login
My nextjs based app deployed in AWS EC2 with nginx as load balancer/reverse proxy  slows down after a while (say after 5 min) specially if the user is logged in.

I am using http only 2 cookies to store encrypted session and profile information.
2. The web site is working as expected if it is accessed with the backend port(3000) along with my server ip, instead of the default
port 80.
3. When I clear the browser cache, session cookies are removed and the web site starts working as normal.
4. Getting frequent 408 status in access logs and subsequent requests also mostly results in 408 status.

Below is my conf file. Please help resolve this issue.
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=YOPACKCACHE:100m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;
#sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
sendfile           on;
tcp_nopush on;
proxy_buffering                 on;
tcp_nodelay                       on;
    keepalive_timeout                 65;
    types_hash_max_size               2048;

    client_header_timeout             3m;
    client_body_timeout               3m;
    send_timeout                      1m;
    client_header_buffer_size         5k;
    large_client_header_buffers       4 16k;

    client_max_body_size              20M;

server {
server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xx;
listen 80 default_server;
listen       [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/yopacks;
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_send_timeout   40s;
    proxy_read_timeout   50s;
    proxy_buffer_size    240k;
    proxy_buffers     240 240k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 240k;
    #proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_hide_header  Vary;
proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding '';
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
    proxy_set_header   Referer $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; }

    location ~* ^/.*\\.(?:jpeg|jpg|gif|png|icu|cur|bmp|webp|gz|svg|ttf)$ {
           proxy_cache YOPACKCACHE;
           expires 7d;
           #add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=36000, immutable";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
    }

    # Serve any static assets with NGINX
    location /_next/static {
            proxy_cache YOPACKCACHE;
            expires 7d;
            alias /var/www/yopacks/.next/static;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=36000, immutable";
    }
        

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /_next/$uri 
    @public;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
    proxy_pass http://myappcluster;

    #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    #proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    #add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    #add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';
    #if_modified_since off;
    #expires off;
    #etag off;

}

    location @public {
            proxy_cache YOPACKCACHE;
            expires 7d;

alias /var/www/yopacks/public;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
            proxy_pass http://myappcluster;

    }


location /nginx_status {
    stub_status;
}

}
############################################################
nginx.conf file as below
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
worker_connections 768;
worker_connections 1000;
multi_accept on;

}
http {
##
# Basic Settings

send_timeout 1800;
upstream myappcluster {
  # The upstream elements lists all
  # the backend servers that take part in 
  # the Nginx load balancer 
    #hash $binary_remote_addr consistent;
    zone upstreams 64K;
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 2;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;
}

##

#types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;


include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
##########################################################
sample extract from access log (ip changed)
41.144.30.98 - - [03/May/2024:06:41:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
41.144.30.98 - - [03/May/2024:06:44:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
client timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading client request headers, client: 41.144.30.98, server: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, request: "GET /?category=Appliances&_rsc=1iwkq HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xxx.xxx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/"
